# Will socket broadcast on time interval ensure that the connection will stay alive?

Tags: javascript, node.js

will something like this

```
setInterval(function(){
    socket.emit('broadcast');
}, 10000);
```

ensure that the connection will stay alive on the client?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

No they won't. It can mostly be used by the client as a suggestion not to close the socket.

There can be multiple reasons for connection close, including socket closed from the client end, loss of internet connectivity etc.

What the `heartbeat` helps you do is tell the client that this socket is still open. So if a client does not recieve a heartbeat for 3x-4x intervals, they can try reconnecting.